# Помогите пожалуйста определить тип выделенного предложения:

Tags: синтаксис

Она мало о нём знала, **даже имя его она узнала лишь благодаря подписи на письме**.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне само оформление предложения не нравится. Предлагаю перестроить:

> Она мало о нём знала, даже имя его ей стало известно лишь благодаря подписи на письме.

А что вас смущает в предложении? Имеем бессоюзное сложное целое, соединенное интонационно.

Comment: большое спасибо!!! простите, я не носитель языка и мало понимаю в терминологии: можно сказать, что "сложное целое" аналогично "главному предложению"?

Comment: Это бессоюзное сложное предложение. Просто я тут свои термины использую. :)

Comment: в задании требуется назвать тип выделенного предложения... боюсь сказать что-то неправильно, но можно сказать, что это простое предложение (которое выделенное) в составе бессоюзного сложного?

Comment: Вы совершенно верно мыслите.

Answer (score 2):

Она мало о нём знала, **даже** имя его она узнала лишь благодаря подписи на письме.

Это БСП **неоднородного состава**, второе предложение является распространительным по отношению к первому.

Также  частица ДАЖЕ придает ему добавочное  (пояснительно- комментирующее) значение.